# Debezium - MySQL manually change binlog position from connect-offsets

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, debezium

I have a running debezium setup for doing CDC from MySQL. Now I want to create one more MySQL connector for another MySQL server. But I don't want snapshot for existing data, I want to start the debezium new connector from a specific file and position.

1. I read some questions from stackoverflow, they told to manually insert the record to `connect-offsets` topic. But if I do this what will happen to my existing setup?
2. On a test server, I tried to set the above solution, but it was not working.

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic connect-offsets
>{"file":"mysql-bin.000002","pos":2012}
>[2019-12-30 05:43:52,666] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 4 on topic-partition connect-offsets-5. Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-12-30 05:43:52,767] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 5 on topic-partition connect-offsets-5, Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-12-30 05:43:52,870] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 6 on topic-partition connect-offsets-5, Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-12-30 05:43:52,975] ERROR Error when sending message to topic connect-offsets with key: null, value: 38 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.ingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, has a null key for a compacted to.
```

Im not sure how to achieve this. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Connect-offsets topic records are used for connectors offset management, For Debezium MySQL connector the records in that topic has the key which contains the connector name and the MySQL server name which you have configured under your connector configurations.

So for this, you will require that key as well if you want to produce record in that topic only then the Debezium connector will be able to read those offsets.